# reading strings from a server buffer with strcmp

Tags: c, strcmp

I am trying to construct a tcp sever to read string from a socket buffer. The buffer on the client's side, which is operated with the following code:

```
n = 0;
    do {
        sign = getchar();
        if(n >= 253) break;
        if (sign =='\n') break;
        buffer[n ++] = sign;
    } while (1);
    buffer [n] = 0;
```

server code reads string from a socket in a loop

```
bzero(buffer,255);
n = read(sock,buffer,255);
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

So far everything is ok.

```
    for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(buffer); k++) {
        string[i ++] = buffer[k];
        if (buffer[k] == 0 ) break;
        if (buffer[k] == '\n' ) break;
    }
    printf("Here is the string: %s\n",string);

    char **dict = dictionary();
    cmp(string, dict);
    free_dictionary(dict);
    exit(0);
}
else close(newsockfd);

char **dictionary() // dictionary code
{
    char **dict = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        dict[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    strcpy(dict[0], "mark");
    strcpy(dict[1], "ala");
    strcpy(dict[2], "wojtek");
    strcpy(dict[3], "tom");
    strcpy(dict[4], "john");
    return (dict);
}
void free_dictionary(char **dict) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        free(dict[i]);
    free(dict);
}

int cmp(char *s1, char *s2[5]) //comparison function
{
    int k = 0;
    int n = 0;
    do {
        if (strcmp(s1, s2[k]) == 0)
        n++;
        k++;
    } while(k < 5);
    if (n > 0)
        printf("Found %d", n);
    else
        printf("Nothing found %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

everything seems ok, except for the fact, that it seems like strcmp does not work. <string.h> included.
For the client sending "ala"
The output is:
"this is s2 mark
this is s2 ala
this is s2 wojtek
this is s2 tom
this is s2 john
Nothing found 0
"

Comment: Why are you allocating fixed-length buffers for variable length strings? Hint: `char*` and `strdup` will make this way less messy. This mysterious `5` that appears through your code without explanation is also an anti-pattern.

Comment: Tip: `for (int i = 0; ...)` is better than `int i; for (i = 0; ...)` You do that in most cases, but not all. Be consistent. C is very unforgiving about tiny mistakes.

Comment: I am learning new things about C everyday, thank you, I will try to rewrite the above.

Comment: You call it "dict" but it's not a "dictionary", that implies key-value pairs. This is just an array of `char*` strings. Are you asking "how can I find a string match in an array of strings"? Your `cmp` function should return a useful value. Printing something doesn't help your code. By convention it should return `-1` on a miss, or the index of a hit if found.

Comment: It's worth testing these functions individually before expecting them to work together. C has many unit testing add-ons that can make this a lot easier to structure, run and verify. Your `cmp()` function may not be working correctly, that `do { ... } while(...)` structure seems out of place. Why not `for`? Iterate and `return` on match, then have a default `return` at the end.

Comment: When testing strings be sure the strings are *actually* the same. It's quite often the case there's an extra space or newline character in there that messes up the comparison. Step through in a debugger if you want to find out exactly what's going on.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not a hash table. It is a quite primitive solution. "Are you asking "how can I find a string match in an array of strings"?" Yes, I am.

Comment: I have tested so called "dicitionary" as a standalone code. It works.

Comment: The really lazy way is to make a string of the form `"|mark|ala|...|"` where the names are bounded by some character that won't appear in the names, then use something like [`strstr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to find any potential matches. This doesn't require special allocations, just a little preparation on the test string.

Comment: `bzero(buffer,255); n = read(sock,buffer,255); printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);` is UB when `buffer` data is 255 in length as `buffer` is not a _string_.  Suggest  `n = read(sock,buffer,254);`

Comment: `printf("Here is the string: %s\n",string); ... cmp(string, dict)` are not valid as `string` is not certainly a _string_.

Comment: You also seem to assume that you will receive a whole tcp message with read. There is no guarantee of any records in tcp. Just that the bytes you send will be received in the order you send them. You could send 1 50 byte message and receive 25 2 bytes messages